# Geometric interpretation of Krull dimension of coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Given an algebraic variety $W\subset \mathbb{k}^n$, with $\mathbb{k}$ any field, one can consider the coordinate ring $K[W]=\mathbb{k}[x_1,...,x_n]/I(W)$. I am wondering whether there is a geometric interpretation for the Krull dimension of this ring.

Can we say something about $W$ (geometrically) knowing the Krull dimension of $K[W]$?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: It's the dimension of $W$ as a topological space. This is covered very early on in most introduction algebraic geometry books.

Comment: @KReiser Why? I agree this is the case if $\mathbb{k}$ is algebraically closed, but how does one prove it for arbitrary $\mathbb{k}$? (This is what OP is asking for.) Using that (i) the assignment $X\mapsto I(X)$ is contravariantly injective for algebraic subsets and (ii) an algebraic subset $X$ is irreducible if and only if $I(X)$ is prime, one deduces $\operatorname{dim}W\leq\operatorname{dim}K[W]$. But how does one show equality? I know that

Comment: it is true for $\mathbb{k}=\mathbb{R}$, by Theorem 3.20 of [these notes](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/SAG.pdf). However, the proof there relies on results from real algebraic geometry, so I don't know if we still have $\operatorname{dim}W=\operatorname{dim} K[W]$ for more general $\mathbb{k}$. So far I've been unable to produce either a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: This has been previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2011081/394668) and hinted at in Question 1 from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4592984/394668). The former post has received no actual answer, whereas the latter has an accepted answer that doesn't address the specific issue of whether $\operatorname{dim}W$ and $\operatorname{dim}K[W]$ coincide or not. (as the OP, I mean $W\subset\mathbb{k}^n$.)